# How do I calculate the most popular device, os, browser in each city in HiveQL?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql, apache-tez

I have a table with user agent strings (which I parse into `browser`, `os`, and `device` columns) and city `id`'s. I want to calculate the most popular `browser`, `os` and `device` for each `city`.

Here's my attempt:

```
select device os, browser, name, MAX(hits) as pop from 
(select uap.device, uap.os, uap.browser, name, COUNT(*) as hits 
from (select * from browserdata join citydata on cityid=id) t 
lateral view ParseUserAgentUDTF(UserAgent) uap as device, os, browser 
GROUP BY uap.device, uap.os, uap.browser, name) t2 
GROUP BY name;
```

So, the inner most subquery, aliased `t` simply joins my table on another table that maps `id`'s to city `name`s, so I can see actual `name`s, instead of city `id`'s in the output.

Then, the subquery named `t2` counts the number of composite keys (`device`, `browser`, `os`, `city`). And the outer query groups everything into `name` windows and extracts the row with the maximum number of users.

The error I get is this:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'device'

I understand what it means. It says that I need to include `device` into `group by`, but if I do, then it won't be calculating what I want. How do I fix my query?

Also, I noticed that some of my hive queries run on mapreduce but don't run on tez. Why is that?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a formatted query would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The first table (browserdata) has (useragent, cityid) rows, the second one(citydata) has (cityid, cityname) rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://ideone.com/SCjb1q I wrote this with the help of someone else, but now it turns out that hive doesn't support lateral joins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions you can eliminate unnecessary join:

```
WITH 
t1 as 
(select * from browserdata join citydata on cityid=id),

t2 as 
(select uap.device as device, uap.os as os, uap.browser as browser, name as cityname 
from t1 
lateral view ParseUserAgentUDTF(UserAgent) uap as device, os, browser),

t3 as
(select t2.cityname as cityname, t2.device as device, t2.browser as browser, t2.os as os, count(*) as count from t2 group by t2.cityname, t2.os, t2.device, t2.browser)

select cityname, maximum,  device, os, browser
 from
     (select cityname, device, browser, os, 
             max(count) over(partition by cityname)                         as maximum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cityname order by count desc ) as rnk      
      from t3
     ) s  where rnk =1 
;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Btw you have a typo in "oartition".

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1 as 
(select * from browserdata join citydata on cityid=id),

t2 as 
(select uap.device as device, uap.os as os, uap.browser as browser, name as cityname 
from t1 
lateral view ParseUserAgentUDTF(UserAgent) uap as device, os, browser),

t3 as
  (SELECT t2.cityname as cityname, t2.device as device, t2.browser as browser, t2.os as os, COUNT(*) as count FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.cityname, t2.os, t2.device, t2.browser),

t4 as
    (select cityname, MAX(count) as maximum from t3 group by cityname)

select t4.cityname, t4.maximum, t3.device, t3.os, t3.browser
from t4 join t3 on t4.cityname=t3.cityname and t4.maximum=t3.count;
```

This works, however I wonder if there's a way to optimize it...

Comment: Shouldn't this be a part of question?

Comment: @leftjoin when I was writing the question I wanted a query that works and this one works, it's just not efficient...

Comment: @leftjoin your improvement with analytic functions also fails... I guess it needs to be optimized further, do you know how? Everything works ok on mapreduce but fails on tez.

Comment: @leftjoin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915059/how-can-i-diagnose-map-x-killed-failed-due-toother-vertex-failure here. I don't understand what's happening, there's no exception.

Comment: @leftjoin if I do "yarn logs -applicationId ..." the log is huge and it's hard to diagnose what's happening.