# How can I fix java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.1.0?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-sandbox, apache-tez

I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.1.0 exception` in my query. Here's the query:

```
WITH 
t1 as 
(select * from browserdata join citydata on cityid=id),

t2 as 
(select uap.device as device, uap.os as os, uap.browser as browser, name as cityname 
from t1 
lateral view ParseUserAgentUDTF(UserAgent) uap as device, os, browser),

t3 as
(select t2.cityname as cityname, t2.device as device, t2.browser as browser, t2.os as os, count(*) as count from t2 group by t2.cityname, t2.os, t2.device, t2.browser)

select cityname, maximum,  device, os, browser
 from
     (select cityname, device, browser, os, 
             max(count) over(partition by cityname)                         as maximum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cityname order by count desc ) as rnk      
      from t3
     ) s  where rnk =1 
;
```

And here's the log from my container:

```
Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Dec 24 16:21:37 +0000 2018

Log Length: 5529

Showing 4096 bytes of 5529 total. Click here for the full log.

.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682) [udf.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185) [tez-runtime-internals-0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292.jar:0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292]
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181) [tez-runtime-internals-0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292.jar:0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292]
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36) [tez-common-0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292.jar:0.7.0.2.6.5.0-292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.1.0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:178) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292-d249a9484f801bbb96f01e7bbd357a58127aaca3e59c783a90c062bf99c9310d.jar:1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:143) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292-d249a9484f801bbb96f01e7bbd357a58127aaca3e59c783a90c062bf99c9310d.jar:1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:102) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292-d249a9484f801bbb96f01e7bbd357a58127aaca3e59c783a90c062bf99c9310d.jar:1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:452) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292-d249a9484f801bbb96f01e7bbd357a58127aaca3e59c783a90c062bf99c9310d.jar:1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292]
    ... 16 more
```

I haven't been able to understand what the problem is, everything works on `mapreduce` but doesn't want to work on `tez`.

I use a user defined function for this query to parse the user agent string in one of the columns.

Comment: Find logs of Map4 failed container. Without them it's impossible to say what is happening

Comment: @leftjoin okay, but where are they? I am on hortonworks.

Comment: on a job tracker. you need Map 4 logs

Comment: @leftjoin I added the logs, I think, is that it?

Comment: Open Task Attempts, find failed attempt and open logs

Comment: @leftjoin I found an exception, but I'm not sure if it's the one, because the time of logging is weird, I noticed it after I removed "syslog" from the end of the url.

Comment: Also run explain to get execution plan and check what Map4 is doing. Maybe the question can be reduced to single subquery

Comment: @leftjoin can you please tell me where I need to "run explain"? I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185734/discussion-between-leftjoin-and-hey-you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Hortonworks-sandbox for HDP 2.6.5, which has Hadoop 2.7.x and Hive 1.2, not Hadoop/Hive 3

Comment: Yes, this is what I figured out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @leftjoin my problem is now resolved. It turns that I was using this library in my `udf.jar` (A jar with my custom user defined function) maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But my `hive` version is `1.2.1`.

So, adding this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

fixed everything for me.

You can see in my logs `udf.jar` being mentioned. This is the jar that I added with the `add jar /path/to/jar` command, but the error is really cryptic...

Also, I want to mention that even if you just added the `udf.jar` to your session and you don't use it in your query, you will still get this error.